# How to execute a short piece of C code atomic

Tags: c, process, atomic

I have this piece of C code:

```
// ... many stuff here ...
if ( ((*(ptr + 0xffce)) & 3) ) {
     *(ptr + 0xffce) |= 3;
     *(ptr + 0xd415) = 1 << var;
}
// ... many stuff here ...
```

where some bits are getting logically linked and the result values are written to the memory.

For my program it is critical that the CPU isn't detracted during the execution of this program part. Therefore it must be executed *atomic* and behave in the way that the code block is indivisible. The scheduler should only be allowed to detract the CPU before or after this `if` block.

How do I achieve this on a *normal* Linux ecosystem (with a user space program)?

**EDIT:** the comments bellow indicate that it might not be possible to execute the code block without having the CPU possibly detracted by the scheduler. The opposite question would be: *is it generally possible to achieve this goal and what do I need to do for that?*

Comment: Use a mutex? That way the user space code cannot see the memory in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @KerrekSB It won't prevent rescheduling, AFAIK..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, it won't, but from user space that's all you can ask for. The scheduler isn't even something whose existence you can prove from user space.

Comment: @KerrekSB As I understand the OP is trying to access some hardware peripheral registers where timing is critical. So basically you *can* prove the existence of the scheduler given an access to, say, some HW clock you can sample.

Comment: atomic cares more about correctness than timing. please explain which one do you want. if you want strict timing then this is a x-y problem and atomic is not what you need.

Comment: If atomic is more about correctness then the timing is the key here. Obviously I'm reading a value from a peripheral device and if a condition is met I write a value. This action (read-then-write) must occur immediately after each other and the CPU can't be detracted from the program in between (let's say after or with three).

Answer (score 1):

In general, writes to HW should be placed in kernel modules. The code you're displaying (writes to hw addresses) will not work in userspace if the platform is protected by MMU or some other memory management. In theory, the user address space is actually different from kernel address space.

When in kernel mode, the solution will most likely present it self. There're many timing/protect mechanisms in the kernel: preempt_disable, spin_locks, in_atomic, interrupts, high priority kernel timers, whatever.

*in general* you can achieve what you're trying to do, by disabling all interrupts, on the given platform. This normally takes an RTOS or kernel code. (Disabling all interrupts will also prevent the scheduler from running.) However, in most platforms this is frowned upon. (With good reason.) So you have to do it, as per the platform guidelines. The "preempt_disable" is a good example on how to disable the scheduler, without disabling all else.